# RoR - Mongoid foreign key inside an hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

Let's say I have two models, in this example a site and a theme, and I want to make a site belong to a theme, but referencing it with a key inside an hash.

```
class Site
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :preferences, type: Hash

  belongs_to :theme, foreign_key: :"preferences.theme_id"

end
```

As you can see the theme_id is stored inside an hash named "preferences", the problem is that with this code mongoid can't find the right theme_id.
How should I deal with this situation?

Comment: That's not possible. But why do want to do so? Foreign key in hash - it's  slow.

Comment: MongoDB *is* a hash, so if you already know that you have certain keys, then just make them fields. Having a hash in a Mongo field is mostly useful if you allow users to customize the fields themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your preferences together and they're structured, you could use an embedded document instead of a plain Hash:

```
class Site
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one :preferences, :class_name => 'Preferences'
end
class Preferences
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :site
  belongs_to :theme
end
```

Your `preferences` would still be a Hash inside the database but you'd get enough Mongoid wrapping to make the association work. If you do this, then you'd say things like:

```
t = site.preferences.theme
```

If you wanted to, you could delegate the `theme` call from `Site` instances to their embedded `preferences`.